# Free Mysql or Python cache

Tags: python, mysql, caching, blob

I update a Mysql database with blobs. Over 2000 blobs, it becomes very slow. (2000 blobs = 44 seconds, 3000 blobs = 5 minutes, 10 seconds). I sliced the blobs into list of 2000, not to avail. I put it to sleep after 2000 blobs, not to avail. I suspect it's a matter of cache (Python or Mysql?). Thx for help.

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime 
import time

start_time_update = datetime.now()

connection=mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password ='12345', database='sakila')

try:
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    sql=("select picture from staff where staff_id=1")
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result=cursor.fetchone()[0]

    #Creating x pictures

    for i in range(3000):
        with open('Sortie/mon_fichier_blob_'+str(i)+'.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(result)

    sql=("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_2 (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ID_author` INT NULL,`ID_publisher` INT NULL, `Image` BLOB NULL, `nom` VARCHAR(200) NULL,PRIMARY KEY (ID));")
    cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()

    fileName = []
    for i in range(3000):
        id=0
        id_aut= i**2
        id_pub = i
        img = None
        nom='Sortie/mon_fichier_blob_'+str(i)+'.jpg'
        tp=(id, id_aut,id_pub,img,nom)
        fileName.append(tp)

    for ind in fileName:
        sql="""INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cursor.execute(sql,ind)
    connection.commit()

    album = dict()
    for i in range(3000):
        with open('Sortie/mon_fichier_blob_'+str(i)+'.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            album['Sortie/mon_fichier_blob_'+str(i)+'.jpg']=f.read()

    list_blob=[]
    for key, value in album.items():
        adq=(value, key)
        list_blob.append(adq)

    for blob in list_blob:
        sql = """UPDATE test_2 SET Image = %s WHERE nom  = %s"""
        cursor.execute(sql, blob)
        connection.commit()

finally:
    connection.close()

time_elapsed_update = datetime.now() - start_time_update 

print('Time elapsed Update Method (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(time_elapsed_update))
```

Comment: What about rethinking your code so it doesn't try to store thousands of images in memory instead ?

Comment: Thx, indeed I do have another method, I insert them instead of updating them, and the curve of insertion is proportional to the number of blobs. I just want to understand Why this is not the case for updating.

Comment: I think you don't get my point... think about your `album` dict, how much ram it eats and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Ain't the solution. I cleared the dictionary, used garbage collector, and the time doubled! I'll stick with "insert" instead of "update". It's way faster, and it gets the job done!

Comment: you _still_ dont get the point: you absolutely dont need this dict at all - an you don't need the `fileName` and  `list_blob` lists either.